# Most efficient way to sum a conditional expression with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently working on a decision tree and need to calculate the entropy in a label vector y (an numpy array). I tried the two following methods to use the entropy formula:

`entropy = sum(-len(y[y == label]) / len(y) * np.log2(len(y[y == label]) / len(y)) for label in labels)`

and

```
        entropy = 0
        for label in labels:
            cond = y == label 
            fraction = len(y[cond]) / len(y)
            entropy += -fraction * np.log2(fraction)
        return entropy
```

When timing the two methods the seconds approach is the fastest. Why is that? I guess it is because I calculate the fraction two times in the same loop in the first approach. Is there any way to make the first approach faster?

"labels" in the above snippets are the following:

`labels = np.unique(y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can even avoid the for loop by directly obtaining the count through `np.unique`:

```
def entropy(y):
    labels, count = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)
    prob = count / len(y)
    return -(prob * np.log2(prob)).sum()
```

Some performance comparisons with the for loop solution:

```
def for_loop_entropy(y):
    entropy = 0
    for label in np.unique(y):
        cond = y == label 
        fraction = len(y[cond]) / len(y)
        entropy += -fraction * np.log2(fraction)
    return entropy
```

```
In [1]: y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 2 * 10 ** 4)

In [2]: %timeit for_loop_entropy(y)
869 µs ± 9.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit entropy(y)
369 µs ± 3.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [4]: y = np.random.randint(0, 100, 2 * 10 ** 4)

In [5]: %timeit for_loop_entropy(y)
2.58 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit entropy(y)
573 µs ± 5.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a useful method! However, when timing this it actually used up to 3 times as long as the for loop. I don't get why.

Comment: @PythonSnake This is generally better for large datasets, because the vectorization function of numpy has a large startup cost. The reason for the slow speed may be that your dataset is small, and the advantages of vectorization here are not obvious.

Comment: My dataset is quite large with about 2e4 points. But I guess that as y gets smaller after some splits are done, the for loop will get quicker compared to the method you showed?

Comment: @PythonSnake I don't know whether the content of your dataset is suitable for this solution, but I used `y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 2 * 10 ** 4)` to test and found that my solution is nearly twice as fast as the for loop. Did you put the `np.unique` computing time into the test?

Comment: I also get a faster computing time with your method on any y vector thats consists of float labels. But my y consists of string labels, I guess that's why the for loop is faster. (Although I still don't get why it should be).